# Error message when playing audio background music

Tags: lua, coronasdk

I've this music and I tried to play a sound, in loops with a duration :

```
function playBackwards(event)  

      audio.play(musicmenu, {channel=1, duration = 7400, loops=-1})
      audio.setVolume(0.3)

end
```

The problem is about the "loops". The music doesn't loop once I put a duration.

Answer (score 1):

Listener "enterFrame" runs playBackward on every frame. You probably don't need to run playBackwards multiple times, so You should rather call it once:

```
playBackwards()
```

instead of:

```
Runtime:addEventListener("enterFrame",playBackwards)
```

Comment: Thank you ! It works without any error message but it doesn't loops as I want. Loop doesn't work with duration :(

Comment: you are missing loop = -1 parameter in audio.play